# Update record in CakePHP 3 without changing 'modified' field

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a specific save action in CakePHP 3 where I don't want the `modified` field to be updated. I don't want to deactive this feature in general, but just for this action.

In CakePHP 2 I could do it by setting `modified` to `false` like this:

```php
$this->save(['field_1' => 'bla', 'field_2' => 'blu', 'modified' => false]);
```

This doesn't work in CakePHP 3 and I couldn't find any suggestions about this in the documentation.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution in the documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html#saving-updates-without-modifying-timestamps

My code now looks like this:

```php
$entity = $this->get($id);
$entity->setDirty('modified', true);
$entity = $this->patchEntity($entity, ['field_1' => 'bla', 'field_2' => 'blu']);
$this->save($entity);
```